# Can I install mysql on El Capitan?

Tags: mysql, macos-sierra

I tried using brew to install mysql on OS El Capitan but got this error:

```
mysql: macOS Sierra or newer is required.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Is there anyway I could install mysql without updating to Sierra? I don't want to have to buy an external hard drive to backup data for the update.

Answer (score -1):

you can use docker for mac and run any image you want.
https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac

P.S. There is no need to install MySQL or anything locally anymore. 
when you run docker, to the user it seems like a local installation, everything can run on the same port. What makes a difference is easy of version and overall management.

Really, give it a try